# Null Pointer Debugging

Tags: android

quick summary of what I'm trying to do.

Using shared preferences so that when a user watches a video a green tick will appear beside it to mark it as complete. Currently getting a null pointer error.

Basically there are two pages - main page and video page. When user lands on the main page the if statement should check the sharepreferences to see if they have already visited the video page. If they have it should display the completedTick imageView.

Please see the code and context below.

MAIN PAGE CODE SNIPPET:

```
 /**
 * Shared preferences variable which is used to store the userId which is captured at the login screen.
 */
private SharedPreferences loginPref, activityPref;   
private ImageView completedTick;
private Boolean activityCompleted;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    loginPref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("loginPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    activityPref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("activityPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    activityCompleted = activityPref.getBoolean("activityCompleted", true);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activities, container, false);

    initialiseRecyclerView(view);
    retrieveActivities();

    if(activityCompleted == false || activityCompleted == null ) {
        completedTick.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
    }else{
        completedTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    return view;

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}

/**
 * Method which is used to initialise the recycler view
 *
 * @param view
 */
private void initialiseRecyclerView(View view) {
    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewActivities);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    EmptyAdapter emptyAdapter = new EmptyAdapter();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(emptyAdapter);
    completedTick = view.findViewById(R.id.completedTick);
}
```

VIDEO PAGE CODE SNIPPET:

```
private SharedPreferences activityPref;
private Boolean activityCompleted;


@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.youtube_layout);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: Starting");
    activityPref = getSharedPreferences("activityPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    activityCompleted = activityPref.getBoolean("activityCompleted", true);

        getExtrasMethod();
        initialiseViews();
        setTextInViews();
        checkCompleteD();


 private void checkCompleteD() {

    if (activityCompleted) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = activityPref.edit();
        activityCompleted = false;
        editor.putBoolean("activityCompleted", activityCompleted);
        editor.apply();

    }
}
```

The error is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.fit.ActivitiesFragment.onCreateView(ActivitiesFragment.java:78)
```

UPDATE:

Made the suggedted changes

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    loginPref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("loginPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    activityPref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("activityPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    activityCompleted = activityPref.getBoolean("activityCompleted", true);

    completedTick = view.findViewById(R.id.completedTickImage);
    initialiseRecyclerView(view);
    retrieveActivities();

    if (activityCompleted == false || activityCompleted == null) {
        completedTick.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        completedTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.feelingfit.ActivitiesFragment.onViewCreated(ActivitiesFragment.java:85)

Which is this line :  completedTick.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: `view.findViewById(R.id.completedTick)` is returning `null`.  Figure out why.

Comment: Try to declare the `findViewById` into the `onCreateView` and tell me if you re getting null or not.

Comment: Its still null, updated the question to show the updates I made to the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your `completedTick` is null. Try putting the `completedTick = view.findViewById(R.id.completedTick);` in your `OnViewCreated` **above** this code:

```
if(activityCompleted == false || activityCompleted == null ) {
        completedTick.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else{
        completedTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

And also,  replace the `view.INVISIBLE` with `View.INVISIBLE`

**Edit + Aditional Information:**

If you occur again the `NullPointerException` please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

**Edit 2:**
Rewrite your code inside the `onViewCreated` method like this:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activities, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
 loginPref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("loginPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        activityPref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("activityPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        activityCompleted = activityPref.getBoolean("activityCompleted", true);

        initialiseRecyclerView(view);
        retrieveActivities();

        if(activityCompleted == false || activityCompleted == null ) {
            completedTick.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            completedTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
}
```

**Edit number 3:** Since it is crashing again on the same use case I assume your `R.id.completedTickImage` is **not** inside your `fragment_activities`

Comment: I think this will do the job because his declarations need to be good.
By the way brravo shqipe mvjen mire qe ka njerz qe punojn ne kete drejtim.

Comment: that's my passion :)

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested but now it gives a null pointer on this line:

if(activityCompleted == false || activityCompleted == null ) {

Comment: ok I will update my answer now

Comment: Copied and pasted that in, still a null pointer......Im gonna scream :'(

Comment: @androidnewbie please check my Edit number 3

Comment: You're right.....its a recyclerView so the fragment_activitie sjust holds the recyclerview the content inside the view is in a different layout file....What do i do?

Comment: Just pass your `ImageView` code inside the fragment that actually holds it.

Comment: This fragment does hold it but its a recyclerview so theres an adapter, the adapter holds the view for each recycler viewholder.

Comment: If that ImageView is inside the `Recyclerview`, you should add that logic inside the `ViewHolder` class in your adapter.

Comment: Thank you Starvro, I managed to get it working with your help. Much appreicated.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck in the development world

Answer (score -1):

Do the operation of `CompleteTick.setVisibility` inside `onActivityCreated()` method and also replace the `view.INVISIBLE` to `View.INVISIBLE`